# The Field of Quotients of An Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

according to Fraleigh,

in the Field of Quotients of An Integral Domain,

( Let D be an integral domain and form the Cartesian product D x D = {(a,b)} | a,b $\in$ D}
and S = {(a,b) | a,b $\in$ D, b is not 0},

let (a,b) , (c,d) are equivalent iff ad= bc
and define F tobe the set of all equivalence classes [(a,b)] for (a,b) $\in$ S.)

**[(-a,b)] is an additive inverse for [(a,b)] in F.**

But, [(-a,b)] + [(a,b)] = [ (ab-ba, b$^2$ ] = [ (0, b$^2$ ]

how is this equal to [(0.1])?

**Also, I'm not sure how to show the distributive laws hold in F.**

I tried to show [(a,b)] ( [(c,d)] + [(e,f)] ) = [(ac, bd)] + [(ae, bf)]
but they are clearly different, since
the left side equals to [(adf+bcf+bde,bdf)]
while the right side equls to [(acbf+bdae, bdbdf)]

Give me some help please!

Comment: Please define your notation: What is $F$, and what is $[(a, b)]$?

Comment: @T.Bongers I just edited my question!

Comment: recall that $(a,s) = (b,t)$ precisely when the usual cross multiplication works (for a field of fractions). that is to say, $at = bs$. in your case, $(0, b^2) = (0, 1)$, as $0 \cdot 1 = 0 \cdot b^2$

Comment: for clarity: putting the square brackets around the tuple means you want things understood *up to the equivalence relation*. so certainly $(0, b^2) \neq (0,1)$ *as tuples*, but they are equal up to the equivalence relation, and that's what we care about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ you were given here for domains was probably $ad=bc$. When two pairs are similar, the classes are the same: $[(a,b)]=[(c,d)]$.

So, is $(0,s)\sim(0,1)$ for any $s\in D\setminus \{0\}$?

Another good thing to establish is that $(a,b)\sim(at,bt)$ for any $b,t\neq 0$, and any $a$, giving you the equality $[(a,b)]=[(at,bt)]$.

For distributivity, you need to check your work. It looks like there were some weird mistakes. You should have $acf+ade$ in the "numerator" of the left-hand side. You also have one too many $d$'s in the "denominator" of the right-hand side.

After you've fixed the mistakes, the "another good thing" I mentioned should carry you home.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence relation in the field of fractions as you are defining it is

$$(a,b)\sim (c,d)\Longleftrightarrow ad=bc$$

Notice this shows that $[(0,b)]=[(0,1)]$ for any $b\ne 0$.  As far as the distributive law, we have:

$$[(a,b)]([(c,d)]+[(e,f)])=[(a,b)][(cf+ed,df)]=[(acf+aed,bdf)]$$

and

$$[(ac,bd)]+[(ae,bf)]=[(acbf+abde,b^2df)]$$

See if you can show, using the equivalence relation, that the two right hand sides are equivalent.